# trying to generate all sub-sequences of string vector using unique pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

Tring to create sub sequence :

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>
allsubsequences(const std::string& sequence)
{
const int n = sequence.size();
<std::vector<std::string>> subsequences(new std::vector<std::string>);
int num = pow(2, n);
for(int i = 0; i<= num-1; i++)
{
std::unique_ptr<std::string> some(new std::string);
for(int j = 0; j<= n-1; j++)
{
if(((i >> j) & 1) == 1)
{
some->push_back(sequence[j]);
}
}
subsequences->push_back(some);
}
return subsequences;
}
```

error for the code given by the compiler is as  :'`std::vector >::push_back(std::unique_ptr >&)

Comment: C++ is not Java, you don't need `new` to construct an object. Any particular reason for `i<= num-1` over `i < num`? also `((i >> j) & 1) == 1` over `(i >> j) & 1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is a type mismatch.

You try to insert a `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` into a `std::vector<std::string>`.

You don't need all those `std::unique_ptr`, `std::vector` and `std::string` already handle memory for you.

You may simply do:

```
std::vector<std::string> generate_all_subsequences(const std::string& sequence)
{
    const int n = sequence.size();

    std::vector<std::string> subsequences;
    int num = pow(2, n);

    for (int i = 0; i <= num - 1; i++) {
        std::string candidate;
        for (int j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++) {
            if (((i >> j) & 1) == 1) {
                candidate.push_back(sequence[j]);
            }
         }
         subsequences.push_back(std::move(candidate));
    }
    return subsequences;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a value to `push_back` rather than a pointer:

```
subsequences->push_back(*candidate);
```